# Python Sqlite3 not updating database

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm working in a project, and i'm facing a issue when trying to update my database...

I'm running the following command:

```
con = sqlite3.connect("DATASETS/SQLite.db")
cur = con.cursor()

with open("DATASETS/test.csv","r") as fin:
    dr = csv.DictReader(fin, ["element1", "element2", "element3", "element4", "element5", "element6", "element7", "element8", "id"])
    to_db = [(i["element1"], i["element2"], i["element3"], i["element4"], i["element5"], i["element6"], i["element7"], i["element8"], i["id"]) for i in dr]

cur.executemany("UPDATE Table SET element1 = ?, element2 = ?, element3 = ?, element4 = ?, element5 = ?, element6 = ?, element7 = ?, element8 = ? WHERE ID = ?;", to_db)

con.commit()
con.close()
```

The data is beeing filtered in a dataset csv with 6000+ rows and delimiter ",".

The code runs without errors, but, when i opened the DB to check, there ware not even a single row that was updated.

I do not know if this is a VSCode bug, a version error (Python 3.8.3), or anything like this, and i wnated to ask if anyone has already saw this.

Thanks!!